# Has anyone done python code for converting timezones among Australian states?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I believe there are possible pitfalls but ignoring the known problem cases and just considering only the other common occurring values of time, has anyone written a function to do Aussie time zone conversion among the different states in Australia (ignoring external territories)?

I know there is pytz, but the module is not available in this environment and it is not a trivial task to get it setup.

Below is code I have drafted per wikipedia specs.

```
# Return converted time from one Australia state timezone to another
# Assumes DST regime is post 12 April 2007 when 5 states agreed to common DST start and end day
# argument tm is a datetime/date
# accuracy benchmark vs pytz shows 5 in 100,000 discrepancy in converting random datetime values in borderline dst cases
def au_tz_convert(fromState, toState, tm):
    tz = {
         'WA' : +8
        ,'NT' : +9.5
        ,'QLD': +10
        ,'SA' : +9.5
        ,'NSW': +10
        ,'VIC': +10
        ,'ACT': +10
        ,'TAS': +10
        }

    if not(fromState in tz and toState in tz):
        raise Exception, "input state values should be in " + str(tz.keys())

    a = tz[fromState]
    b = tz[toState]

    from datetime import timedelta, datetime

    def dst(auState, tm):

      if auState in ['WA','NT','QLD']:
        return 0

      #DST start is first Sunday in October
      #DST end is first Sunday in April

      dst_start = datetime(tm.year,10,1,  2)
      dst_end   = datetime(tm.year, 4,1,  2)
      while dst_start.weekday() != 6:
        dst_start +=  timedelta( days=1 )
      while dst_end.weekday()   != 6:
        dst_end   +=  timedelta( days=1 )

      if tm < dst_end or tm >= dst_start:
        return 1
      return 0

    f = dst(fromState, tm)
    t = dst(toState  , tm)    
    return  tm + timedelta( hours = b-a + t-f )
```

Comment: You should rephrase your question. As it stands, it's a simply "yes" or "no" answer, which isn't going to help you or future visitors. What exactly are you asking for? (Keep in mind that asking for someone to provide you the code is going to be "Too Broad", and asking for other third-party modules or libraries is off-topic as well.)

Comment: why would it be too broad to ask for code for a problem that is specific?

Comment: There is an expectation on SO that you demonstrate some effort you've put into solving the problem yourself, and you haven't done so here. This reads like a "gimme the code" question, which usually collect "too broad" close votes. You're right that this *is* a pretty specific problem, so the range of possible solutions may not be very wide, and this question may not get the close votes I expect. Either way, get rid of "has anyone done..." and focus your question title on exactly what you need. It would help to highlight any other research you've done too.

Comment: The only other improvement to this is the actual code itself. I'll put up my draft in an edit in a bit. I do not follow the "if anyone has done" issue. Isn't that partly the object of sharing a question, is to avoid having to reinvent the wheel if someone else has done the work. Otherwise, where else would it be proper this question? Its also not like there is no research and effort shown in the writing of the question. But your issue is of lack of highlight?

Comment: The problem here is that the canonical way to solve such a problem **is** pytz. So the probability for someone to have re-invented it from scratch is IMHO low. My advice is that is will certainly be simpler to have pytz installed that redevelop everything. If it is really impossible because of your requirements, you should get its source and start from there...

Comment: Or I can run a compare benchmark of solution against pytz

Comment: Suppose the answer is yes, Carl Smith from a small town in Ohio has written Python code for converting time zones between Australian states. What do you do next?

Comment: I've done it. See update in code comments